# Vectorization of arrays containing lambda functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

I have two arrays, one which has floats in it (We'll call array 1), the other (array 2) has mostly INF's in it, with a few lambda functions at certain locations. Both are 4x4 arrays

Basically, all I want to do is cross these two arrays, with the lambda function computing the value  for the respective cell, and thus creating a new array (call array 3).

As a basic outline

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],   #Array 1 (values won't always be zero, will be a mix as the program proceeds)
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]],

combined with

([[inf, (<function <lambda> at 0x000002206D61F4C0>,),
  (<function <lambda> at 0x000002206D61F550>,), inf],
  [inf, inf, (<function <lambda> at 0x000002206D61F700>,),    #Array 2 (actual lambda array)
  (<function <lambda> at 0x000002206D61F5E0>,)],
  [inf, inf, inf, (<function <lambda> at 0x000002206D61F670>,)],
  [inf, inf, inf, inf]]

to give 

  
=   [0, 4, 9, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 1],   #Array 3 (random numbers here, 0 values that weren't at lambda locations could
    [0, 0, 0, 7],   #could also be INF's, doesn't matter. 
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I've thought of some for loop that could index the values in the range somehow and then just loop through, that seems convoluted and theres a few confusing approaches that could be taken here.

But i'm thinking there must be a far simpler vectorization approach thats possible.

Any help here appreciated

Comment: why would you put functions/lambdas in a numpy array? As you'll have object I think you can never vectorize your code. The real question is what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: There isn't a numpy function or tool to do this for you.  You have to loop.

Comment: If the 2 arrays were actually lists, you could do something like `[fun(val) if 'callable(fun) else val for fun,val in zip(funlist, vallist)]`.  Your array with lambdas is object dtype.  Any math on object dtype arrays is done at list comprehension speeds (or slower).  Object dtype arrays are essentially bastardized lists, with few, if any, advantages.